# Docker: Access the webapp running in google cloud VM (Ubuntu)

Tags: docker, networking, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, ubuntu-16.04

I am running an image and created a container for one of the open project `BusyBox`.
Below are my container details.

```
:~$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                   CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES
1ea15ec5dac5        busybox               "sh"                      16 hours ago        Up 16 hours         0.0.0.0:80->8080/tcp      tt3
df236d039aa1        busybox               "sh"                      17 hours ago        Up 17 hours         0.0.0.0:32769->8080/tcp   bb1
```

I am trying to access the container using the URL http://GoogleExternalIP:32769 and http://GoogleExternalIP:80 but getting the error like `This site can’t be reached 35.231.34.38 refused to connect. Search Google for 231 32769 ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Note: My Jenkins is running on the port 8080 and I can access it. But Jenkins is installed on VM. but the apps which I want to access are running in Docker Containers. 
    I have set up the Google firewall to allow all incoming for all ports.

Comment: I would double check the firewall to make sure everything is set correctly. Also check if you can `curl  [containerip]:[port]` from inside the gce (to get your containerip run `docker inspect [containername]`

Comment: @jerom987, Thank you so much for the reply. I got below error when I tried   "curl [containerip]:[port]" . Error=curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.2 port 32769: Connection refused.

Comment: Are you sure something is running on port 8080 in busybox then?

Comment: This is the output of the command "docker ps"(check the next comments), Total 4 contianers are running and I used port forwarding for all of them.

Comment: sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                   CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES
debbbfde7040        shvkumara/calculator:1   "/bin/sh -c '\"catali…"   43 hours ago        Up 43 hours         0.0.0.0:32776->8080/tcp   tender_liskov
70ae3c2f6799        shvkumara/deploy:19      "/bin/sh -c '\"catali…"   2 days ago          Up 2 days           0.0.0.0:32773->8080/tcp   MyContainder-19

Comment: 1ea15ec5dac5        busybox                  "sh"                      2 days ago          Up 2 days           0.0.0.0:80->8080/tcp      tt3
df236d039aa1        busybox                  "sh"                      2 days ago          Up 2 days           0.0.0.0:32769->8080/tcp   bb1

Comment: Could you `curl [containerip]:8080` from inside a docker host?

Comment: Hi when I tried "curl [host-ip]:32769 and "curl [containerip]:32769" i got same error "curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.1 port 32769: Connection refused"    (Busybox is running on 32769 port, busybox 0.0.0.0:32769->8080/tcp   bb1)